# Project reference conditional include with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, include, conditional-statements, csproj, buildconfiguration

Here's a snippet from my csproj file:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\program_data\program_data.csproj" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
      <Project>{4F9034E0-B8E3-448E-8794-CF9B9A5E7D46}</Project>
      <Name>program_data</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

What I'd like to do is include `program_data.dll` for **multiple** build configurations, for example, both Release and Debug.

I tried doing the following

```
Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug' || '$(Configuration)'=='Release'"
```

but Visual Studio chokes on this.

Is there a way I can do this, or must I have a separate `<ProjectReference>` for each build config?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You should use [`Or`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx), not `||`:

```
Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug' Or '$(Configuration)'=='Release'"
```

Comment: @Charlie - I have linked to the MSBuild conditionals documentation.

Comment: I noticed that, thanks. I find the MSDN library can be tricky unless you know *what* you're looking for.

Comment: If you want your reference work for both Release and Debug, and you don't have any other configurations, it is simpler to make your ProjectReference unconditional by removing the "Condition" attribute.

Comment: @Oleg I would imagine they have more than just `Debug` and `Release`, otherwise no need for the question. I have a few solutions that also have `Debug MONO` and `Release MONO`.

Comment: Can I have my own Condition? in case I only want to reference this library in case that condition is set? and if so how do I set it

Comment: @SaherAhwal - I think this is possible. But you will need to pass in the conditions to the build. Your code would have to be able to compile differently as well, depending on this condition (which is not as straight forward, I believe). I suggest taking a deeper look into MSBuild, the build system that uses these.

Comment: thanks I was able to do it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540757/user-defined-condition-variable-for-package-referencing-in-c-sharp-net-core

Comment: You can also use `and`