# Include file only if specified constant is defined in C# project

Tags: c#, project, constants

I have an application that have many .xaml files, how can i make this project include some files only if specified constant (example TEST) is defined?

Thanks!

Comment: a normal if statement should suffice your requirements. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is this what you want - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312098/project-reference-conditional-include-with-multiple-conditions?